# cant locate MozRepl.pm in @INC

Tags: perl, www-mechanize, par, www-mechanize-firefox, mozrepl

I have a Perl script which uses WWW::Mechanize::Firefox which works well before its been converted into Executable file by using PAR::Packager.

it shows an error as

```
Can't locate MozRepl.pm in @INC
```

Need some suggestion to solve this issue, Thank you

@mpapec

Update

```
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath; 
use MozRepl;
use HTML::Entities ();
use Encode::Byte;
use Encode::Alias;
use Encode::Config;
use WWW::Mechanize;
use URI;
use v5.14; 
use utf8;
use Text::CSV_PP;
use Text::CSV;
use strict;
use warnings;

use autodie qw(:all);
use HTML::Entities;
```

Comment: Try with `use MozRepl;` on top of your script.

Comment: What platform are you on?

Comment: @mpapec : Thanks,now it says `Failed to connect to ,  can't locate object method "setup" via package "MozRepl::Client" at MozRepl.pm line 224`

Comment: If this message is from "compiled" script, add all reported modules on top of script.

Comment: @mpapec :Thank you so much, your comment solved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

This error usually relates to the fact you do not have MoxRepl.pm installed in your INC path.  MozRepl is a library you would download from (https://metacpan.org/pod/MozRepl)

Depending on your environment this could be done in various ways but on a mac or linux you can try

`sudo cpan install MozRepl` to have CPAN download the module.

If that doesn't work then you have an issue with your environment and perl doesn't know where to look for the modules and you would need to investigate changing your INC path (maybe this link:  http://perlmaven.com/how-to-change-inc-to-find-perl-modules-in-non-standard-locations)

But my guess would be you are missing the module.

If you are using ActiveState perl for windows you can try `ppm` from a command prompt to launch a visual module installer

Comment: He's trying to create an executable distribution. The executable distribution is suppose to contain everything needed, including Perl itself. Saying to install the module using some other Perl that may or may not be present on the machine is incorrect.